# study roadmap for newcomer into java ee

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm the newcomer into java ee,I have studied about core java,servlet,jsp.
Could anyone give me some suggestion(some books,forums,etc) on how to promote my skills into java ee?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good place to start is Sun's [Java 6 EE Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/index.html) on the Sun web site.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Server-Based Java Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1884777716). This isn't a Java EE book per se, but it explains *what* a Java based server needs to do and how to do it with good example code. It will give you the foundation to understand to understand what Java EE is trying to accomplish and why things are the way they are.

In the same vein, I would recommend [Expert One-on-One J2EE Development without EJB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764558315). This book is written by the founder of the Spring project and provides insight to the problems with Java EE that Spring is trying to solve. Note this was written before Spring was open sourced, so it's more a 'this is how a server framework that's *not* Java EE could work' book, not a 'how to use Spring' book. Even if you are using straight Java EE, it helps to know what issues you could run into (with J2EE) or what the motivations were for Java EE 5 (based on Spring & Hibernate philosophies).

I would not recommend the actual specifications from Sun. They are dense, technical and better used as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

To be an effective J2EE developer, you'll have to have a few frameworks under your belt. Start boning up on Spring, JSF, Hibernate, etc.

For more details, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450906/important-frameworks-tools-to-learn/451162#451162).

Spring is an excellent first choice of framework, for reasons that may not become apparent until you've used it on a large project. But the best tutorial I know for learning it is Manning's [Spring In Action](http://www.manning.com/walls3/).